# Smooth player jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game with Unity where player pick up a cookie and then player is jumping on y-axis. When player is jumping, he is twitching(very much). I want that jump and I want see that player is jumping smoothly. 
This is my sample of code

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
    player.velocity = new Vector2 (0, 0);
    player.AddForce(new Vector2(0,jumpHeight));
}
```

I tested about 1000f value of jumpHeight. Same problem is with higer or lower value.

UPDATE: This is my sample of Camera Moving code:

```
void Update () 
    {
        playerHeightY = player.position.y;
        float currentCameraHeight = transform.position.y;
        float newHeightOfCamera = Mathf.Lerp (currentCameraHeight, playerHeightY, Time.deltaTime * 10f);

        if (playerHeightY > currentCameraHeight) 
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, newHeightOfCamera, transform.position.z);
        } 
}
```

Thanks and kind regards

Comment: Have you tried leaving out resetting of the player velocity?

Comment: @Dawnkeeper I solve my problem. Check solution on my updated post :) Thanks

Comment: @mavericks don't post solutions in your question, either delete your question or post an answer and accept the answer after the minimum time limit has passed.

Comment: Thats nice =) You could post the solution as an answer and accept it. This would fit the site better than the edit.

Comment: Ok. I will. Thanks for suggestion :) @ScottChamberlain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just raised newHeightOfCamera value from 10f to 100f and now, player is moving up very very smooth. I hope that this post will be help for someone. Thanks :)

```
void Update () 
    {
        playerHeightY = player.position.y;
        float currentCameraHeight = transform.position.y;
        float newHeightOfCamera = Mathf.Lerp (currentCameraHeight, playerHeightY, Time.deltaTime * 100f);

        if (playerHeightY > currentCameraHeight) 
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, newHeightOfCamera, transform.position.z);
        } 
}
```